typescript conditional return type with undefined
Below the function I currently have.
But unfortunately I got the following error:

Type '(T & undefined) | { obj: T & ({} | null); }' is not assignable
to type 'T extends undefined ? undefined : { obj: T; }'.   Type 'T &
undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends undefined ? undefined
: { obj: T; }'.(2322)

function undefinedOrObject<T>( param: T ): T extends undefined ? undefined: {obj: T} {
    return typeof param === 'undefined' ? param : { obj: param } 
}

param can be of type number, boolean or undefined. In case of undefined I just want to return undefined. In case of an other primitive type I would like to get an object like {obj: param}. My goal is to solve this without any casting with as .... Any idea how to do this?

This is not currently possible, see ms/TS#33912. For now you need a type assertion (what you're calling "casting"). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate source. If not, what am I missing?

Thanks @jcalz
Overloading seems to be an alternative:
function undefinedOrObject<T extends (number| boolean | undefined)> (obj: T ): T extends undefined ? undefined : { obj: T }
function undefinedOrObject<T>( param: T ) {
    return typeof param === 'undefined' ? undefined : {obj: param}
}


const u = undefinedOrObject(undefined)
const n = undefinedOrObject(3)
const o = undefinedOrObject({t:7}) // There is an error here, which is fine



Overloading is equivalent to “casting” in terms of safety. You can change that === to !== and the compiler wouldn’t care.
